# Modelling an entity with a collection property

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection, data-modeling, class-design

I want to design a Movie class. Now a movie will have a number of genres assigned to it. Ex. The movie Avengers has genres : Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi. Now my application maintains a list of all the genres from which a subset can be assigned to a movie.

My existing model design has a Movie entity with a collection of the entire Genre list. The Genre class simply has an IsSelected property to help identify the subset of genres that have been assigned to a particular movie. This offers an advantage as when I design the user interface to create a new movie, I display all available genres out of which the user selects/checks the ones applicable to the movie.

```
public class Movie
{
    public ObservableCollection<Genre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
}
```

However, I believe this one downside to this approach. Supposing I have around 25 list of genres and around 500 movies, then around 25 x 500 genre objects are created.

Do you think this should be avoided ?

Is there any better approach to associate the genres with a movie object which will reduce the need to create so many genre objects as well as offer the same UI advantage ?

Or is there any better approach to design my user interface that I can leverage from by model design ?

(I am not using any ORM tool, neither planning to use in the future)

Comment: I'd only store genres assigned to that movie on the movie object, and have a separate functionality for adding new genres. Think of the SE system for adding tags for example. If you really want to maintain a "show all genres and select/unselect items", then I'd have a single list of all Generes and sync the checked states with the selectedMovie.Genres list some other way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is certainly not the recommended one for a problem like yours.

Normally, one would define a multi-valued reference property `genres` in the `Movie` class, and this property would hold only the genres assigned to a specific movie.

Notice that, logically/conceptually, you deal with a unidirectional association between `Movie` and `MovieGenre`, assigning genres to movies.

Comment: The first part of your answer seems convincing. However having an enumeration of genres would make it a fixed list. The global genre list can grow or shrink managed by the user. Anyways, I think I'll figure it out. My main concern now is how to program the UI to sinc up with the subset of genres assigned to the respective movies. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, you are right, if the list of genres is not (pretty much) fixed, then you cannot use an enumeration, but need another class. I'll edit my answer.